# How can I compile my .tex file into a .pdf in terminal?

Tags: compiling

I am probably trying to do the simplest thing with LaTeX, that is compile my test.tex file that I made in TeXShop into a .pdf so that I can view it as a pdf.

I am running OS X El Capitan, which I downloaded MacTeX on.

After reading a few stackexchange questions I found the terminal command

```
pdflatex <filename>
```

However, this gives me a "command not found" error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that a correctly installed MacTeX should give you the command. On my computer `which pdflatex` gives `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Is there a way to check if it has installed correctly? I downloaded it from https://tug.org/mactex/ and I didn't notice any problems during

Comment: But did you actually install it? As far as TeXShop is concerned please update it via TeXSop->Check for Updates since newer versions will auto-configure to what is needed under El Capitan. Finally, unless you've changed the path yourself, `which pdflatex` should return /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex; did you set up your own PATH variable?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Yup it was installed, also if I type `which pdflatex` in terminal it doesn't return anything..however I can `cd` into /textbin and I see /pdflatex within

Comment: Do you have this, and can you run it? : `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Comment: In your System Preferences do you have something called `TeX Distribution`? Can you run the GUI tool `LaTeXiT`?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen I'm pretty new to terminal so bear with me lol, if I do `open /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` a new terminal window pops up called pdfTeX

Comment: Do `cd /Library` then `cd TeX` then `cd texbin` and finally `./pdflatex` (broken up on purpose to see where it goes wrong)

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Ok yeah it brings me to pdfTeX, however if I try to type in the input file name it says it can't find it

Comment: You are now in the directory where pdflatex is (because of the `cd`), so you need to go back where your input file is(use `cd`, `cd ...`). -and then run `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex inputfile.tex`

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Not sure if something is wrong with how it is setup but that just opened the original source input file in TeXShop, no .pdf opened

Comment: Did you typeset the source file? In TeXShop use Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T). Also did you update TeXShop? Finally, I want to confirm that you are using Yosemite not El Capitan. Oh, one more thing; what does the command `echo $PATH` return when run in Terminal?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Is it required to run TeX Live Utility to update the system? Wasn't the original MacTeX 2015 not El-Captain aware? Or did that only apply to editors and such?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Okay typesetting opened up a pdf of my .tex and it saved a .pdf to the same location my .tex file was. And I am in fact runniung El Capitan but I believe that the original problems with MacTeX and El Capitan were caused when one had MacTeX already downloaded and then upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan.

Comment: @cfr: MacTeX-2015 was El Capitan aware. It created the link at /Library/TeX/texbin and properly changed the PATH variable to reflect that change. However the TeXShop shipped with MacTeX did not automatically to use that link; later versions did the change automatically. The other GUI apps supplied also didn't change the path automatically and had to be updated or changed manually.

Comment: @user5983828: that would do it. El Capitan removed the original link at /usr/texbin and doesn't allow writing to that directory so it couldn't be recreated. That's why the new link at /Library/TeX/texbin was created.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thanks. I wasn't clear about that - I just knew some stuff had to be updated or modified re. GUIs and wasn't sure about the underlying TL configuration.